# MySQL Query Execution Plan With Limit Different Based on Where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with a limit that is providing dramatically different execution times based on the value in a where close. I'm using MySQL 5.1, and looking at around 100,000,000 records in my biggest table "alerts".

When I see this execution plan, I am happy, and my query takes less than a second:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT alert.id, category.severity, category.classification, category.completion, alert.description,
->        alert.detectTime, analyzer.name, analyzer.manufacturer, analyzer.model, analyzer.version,
->        analyzer.class, analyzer.osType, analyzer.osVersion, analyzerNode.hostName,
->        analyzerNode.address, sourceNode.hostName, sourceNode.address, targetNode.hostName,
->        targetNode.address, sourceUser.userName, sourceUser.uid, targetUser.userName, targetUser.uid,
->        alert.filePath, alert.sourceProcessPid, alert.sourceProcessPath, alert.targetProcessPid,
->        alert.targetProcessPath, alert.acknowledgeUserName, alert.acknowledgeTime, reference.url, reference.meaning
-> FROM alerts AS alert
->      LEFT JOIN categories AS category ON category.id = alert.categoryId
->      LEFT JOIN analyzers AS analyzer ON analyzer.id = alert.analyzerId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS analyzerNode ON analyzerNode.id = alert.analyzerNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS sourceNode ON sourceNode.id = alert.sourceNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS targetNode ON targetNode.id = alert.targetNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN users AS sourceUser ON sourceUser.id = alert.sourceUserId
->      LEFT JOIN users AS targetUser ON targetUser.id = alert.targetUserId
->      LEFT JOIN `references` AS reference ON reference.id = alert.referenceId
-> WHERE category.severity = 'info'
-> ORDER BY alert.id DESC
-> LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0;
```

- | id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | alert        | index  | categoryIndex         | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                    |   40 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | category     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,severityIndex | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.categoryId     |    1 | Using where |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | analyzer     | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.analyzerId     |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | analyzerNode | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.analyzerNodeId |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | sourceNode   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.sourceNodeId   |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | targetNode   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.targetNodeId   |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | sourceUser   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.sourceUserId   |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | targetUser   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.targetUserId   |    1 |             |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | reference    | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | am.alert.referenceId    |    1 |             |

But when I just change the value of the where clause (which in this case is an enum but I don't think that's relevant) I can get dramatically different results and my query takes forever.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT alert.id, category.severity, category.classification, category.completion, alert.description,
->        alert.detectTime, analyzer.name, analyzer.manufacturer, analyzer.model, analyzer.version,
->        analyzer.class, analyzer.osType, analyzer.osVersion, analyzerNode.hostName,
->        analyzerNode.address, sourceNode.hostName, sourceNode.address, targetNode.hostName,
->        targetNode.address, sourceUser.userName, sourceUser.uid, targetUser.userName, targetUser.uid,
->        alert.filePath, alert.sourceProcessPid, alert.sourceProcessPath, alert.targetProcessPid,
->        alert.targetProcessPath, alert.acknowledgeUserName, alert.acknowledgeTime, reference.url, reference.meaning
-> FROM alerts AS alert
->      LEFT JOIN categories AS category ON category.id = alert.categoryId
->      LEFT JOIN analyzers AS analyzer ON analyzer.id = alert.analyzerId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS analyzerNode ON analyzerNode.id = alert.analyzerNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS sourceNode ON sourceNode.id = alert.sourceNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN nodes AS targetNode ON targetNode.id = alert.targetNodeId
->      LEFT JOIN users AS sourceUser ON sourceUser.id = alert.sourceUserId
->      LEFT JOIN users AS targetUser ON targetUser.id = alert.targetUserId
->      LEFT JOIN `references` AS reference ON reference.id = alert.referenceId
-> WHERE category.severity = 'high'
-> ORDER BY alert.id DESC
-> LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0;
```

- | id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys         | key           | key_len | ref                     | rows    | Extra                                        |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | category     | ref    | PRIMARY,severityIndex | severityIndex | 2       | const                   |       8 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | alert        | ref    | categoryIndex         | categoryIndex | 8       | am.category.id          | 3883428 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | analyzer     | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.analyzerId     |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | analyzerNode | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.analyzerNodeId |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | sourceNode   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.sourceNodeId   |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | targetNode   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.targetNodeId   |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | sourceUser   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.sourceUserId   |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | targetUser   | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.targetUserId   |       1 |                                              |
- |  1 | SIMPLE      | reference    | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 8       | am.alert.referenceId    |       1 |                                              |

Notice how the one has the limit as the first step in execution, and the other does not. Is there anyway to force the MySQL query optimizer to perform the limit first like this?

Comment: What happens if you change the first join into an `INNER JOIN`? _Your `WHERE` effectively makes it one anyways, so it shouldn't change your results._

Comment: You can use optimizer hints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html. Another way might be to add indexes that make the bad execution plan good or make the optimizer create another plan.

Comment: The INNER JOIN did not change the performance of the query or the execution plan. As for optimizer hints, I honestly didn't see anything that grabbed me as the solution to my problem (making the limit go first). I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When using a ORDER BY and LIMIT it's important that the order by is on an index.

In case the optimizer decides to pick up another index, the limit is not applied as results are retrieved and a lot more records are scanned.

In your case you probably have less 'high' than 'info' alerts and the optimizer favors the severity index in the category table.

You can try to force the PK of the alert table with `FORCE INDEX` or try to ignore the Severity index of the category table.

This [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/) about it seems useful.